# Joomla: Unable to decompress data OSX folder permissions?

Tags: joomla-3.x, file-permissions, localhost

I installed a blank new installation of Joomla3.3 on my localhost. I am trying to install a plugin, but I keep getting the error message "unable to decompress data".

Joomla attempts to create a install directory in the Joomla's `tmp` folder what seems to fail. At least I cant see the folder Joomla tried to use what would explain the failed decompression.

Now I did `sudo chmod 777` on the `tmp` folder, but to my surprise that did not solve my problem. Joomla still seems to be unable to create a folder in its tmp directory.
I also checked the server-settings, the tmp folder entry points to the correct folder where everyone (my user, but also `everyone`) has full r/w privileges.

I am using XAMPP(MySql, Apache) and OSX (Mavericks). Anyone any idea where my permission problem comes from or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It's undoubtedly a permissions issue, possibly because the user Apache is run under does not have sufficient privileges.

If you're on OSX then I'd recommend you use MAMP instead, designed for OSX, it works out of the box:

http://www.mamp.info/en/